# How can I make a button hidden in a table when pressed in WatchKit

Tags: objective-c, watchkit

I have a table of rows. Within a row I have a group and a button. I want the button to be hidden when pressed.

If I create an outlet I get this message.
Illegal Configuration: The button outlet from the ItemInterfaceController to the WKInterfaceButton is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

In an iPhone app accessing a button in UITableViewCell is quite easy but I'm unsure how to do this in WatchKit.

Answer (score 2):

I read the apple documentation now. One can do this by creating a NSObject class for your row controller. Then change the class of the row controller to the one you created then you can create outlets to the buttons like that. Pretty much same way as UITableViewController in iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the alpha =  0 that button to 0 to make it hidden from user .